# Javascript leafletjs get user position for distance calc

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geopositioning

I'm currently trying to create a map application, so far the map loads and the custom information and icons work flawlessly. I'd, however, like to show the user how far away (distance) to the marker on the map.

This code is working, but I'd like the "from" variable to be the users current position instead of a predetermined position.

```
var onePlace = L.marker([63, 20], {icon: thisIcon}).bindPopup('My text'),
    theOtherPlace = L.marker([65, 20], {icon: thatIcon}).bindPopup('My text');

var to = onePlace.getLatLng();
var from = theOtherPlace.getLatLng();
var distance = from.distanceTo(to);
```

To set the users position on the map I use the code from their quickstart guide whick looks something like this

```
    primaryMap.locate({
    });

    primaryMap.on('locationfound', positionFound);
    primaryMap.on('locationerror', positionNotFound);

    function positionFound(e) { 

    var myPosition = L.marker(e.latlng, {
    }).addTo(primaryMap);
}    
    function positionNotFound(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
```

But how to get the position that I set here in a later stage is what I'm struggling with.

Basically, what I want is this

```
var myPos = [??].getLatLng();
var to = onePlace.getLatLng();
var distance = myPos.distanceTo(to);
```

Sorry for the strange formatting on some of the code, first time posting.

Anyway, if someone could help me out here I'd be incredibly thankful. Been stuck on this one problem for forever and can't seem to find anything helpful in the documentation (probably just don't quite understand it as I'm rather new to this).

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xcyniic/98sy6zxb/27/
Maybe this can help shed some light on what I'm doing / have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the latlng from the `locationfound` event.

```
primaryMap.on('locationfound', positionFound);
function positionFound(e) { 
   var myPos = e.latlng;
   var to = onePlace.getLatLng();
   var distance = myPos.distanceTo(to); 
}
```

**Update**

To get the pos value outside you have to create the variable outside and test if it is not null;

```
var myPos = null;
primaryMap.on('locationfound', positionFound);
function positionFound(e) { 
   myPos = e.latlng;
   calcDistances();
}


function calcDistances(){
   if(myPos){
      var to = onePlace.getLatLng();
      var distance = myPos.distanceTo(to); +

      var to2 = twoPlace.getLatLng();
      var distance = myPos.distanceTo(to2); 

      //...
   }
}
```

I think that you are thinking wrong. The locationfound event is not called immediately, it is a async service. So you have to calc the distance after the event is called and the user position is found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is something I've tried, unfortunately I need to be able to access myPos from outside of the positionFound function (got more than one position that the user should be able to see their distance to). 

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but if I try to access myPos from outside the position function I just get an error saying it's not defined (outside the scope I'd presume.).

Comment: I've tried with the code you entered but myPos is always null. I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong.. My endgoal is something like this: 

    myPlace = L.marker([63, 20], {icon: myIcon}).bindPopup('My text' + myPos.distanceTo(myPlace);

But since I can't get myPos this isn't working.

Comment: I guess the end would look more like: myPlace = L.marker([63, 20], {icon: myIcon}).bindPopup('My text' + myPos.getLatLng().distanceTo(myPlace.getLatLng());

Comment: Can you pls create a example on jsfiddle.net? And try if the marker is placed `function positionFound(e) { L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)}`

Comment: Thanks, and I think you're onto something. For some reason the call to positionFound happens after I've tried to get the value of myPos.. Still no idea why since it should've been called way before my distance function... I'll try to add a jsfiddle a little later.

Comment: Here is a jfiddle, tried to take away as much unnessecary code as possible.. https://jsfiddle.net/98sy6zxb/19/

Comment: You have to call `addMarkers()` in the event `locationfound` else you can not get latlng from the location. https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/qfgxdeyu/

Comment: Thank you very much. This has truly been a pain in my a**! Incredibly greatful that you took the time to help a confused beginner such as myself! Hope you have a great week!